# Debugger not stepping over/into async/wait

Tags: c#, debugging, async-await, azure-blob-storage

I'm testing some code in isolation and it works runs just fine - the debugger steps through every line and returns the intended result. Here is some of the code that I'm testing in isolation:

```
static async Task<List<string>> GetExclusionDataAsync(Uri blobUri)
{
       var listOfExclusions = new List<string>();

       var blobDownloadInfo = await StreamBlobData(blobUri);

       using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(blobDownloadInfo.Content))
       {
             while (!reader.EndOfStream)
             {
                 string exclusionRow = reader.ReadLine();
                 listOfExclusions.Add(exclusionRow);
              }
        }
       return listOfExclusions;
}

private static async Task<BlobDownloadInfo> StreamBlobData(Uri blobPathUri)
{
      BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(blobPathUri);
      BlobDownloadInfo blobDownloadInfo = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
      return blobDownloadInfo;
}
```

I have copied this test code (almost) exactly into another, much larger, dev. solution. When I set my breakpoint on the `BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(blobPathUri);` line, debug, and try to step over/into this line, the debugger skips the rest of the code in the method and jumps back into the prior method without the intended data. See below:

Debugger starts on line 75.

[image]

I then step over/into and the debugger skips to line 60 (the calling method) with no data.

[image]

How do I fix this/what is going on?

I'm new to asynchronous programming and retrieving stuff from blob storage. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't skip to that line, it hasn't executed past that line. So the call has not yet been awaited, hence the line itself is yellow. Had it returned with no data, the next line would be yellow. In your isolated project, you call apparently completes synchronously, which it's allowed to do. Technically an async function does return to the caller at its first incomplete `await`, and then the caller's `await` awaits it.

Comment: Look in the toolbar of Visual Studio. Does the "Thread" number change when it jumps back up?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Are you referring to VS>debug>windows>threads? I think this is what you're referring to. When I have this window open while debugging and step through the code as illustrated above, the thread count seemingly randomly increases or decreases as I step through. I tried this around 10 times and the end result is the  thread count goes up sometimes and down sometimes. I'm confused.

Comment: Sure, that window works too. There will be a yellow arrow in that window showing the thread that you are currently debugging. I'm wondering if it's jumping to a different thread.

Comment: I actually just figured out what the problem was. I needed to install azure.storage.blobs to my calling project (I'm working with multiple projects) so it was just reference related. Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: @JustinFeistner, please add an answer to your question:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm adding the answer to close this issue.

To step into/over, you need to install the package azure.storage.blobs to your calling project, so it was just reference related. Then during debug, you can step into/over it.